# adjacent date element in array

Tags: iphone, exception, comparison, nsdate

how to compare an adjacent array element that contains date. The thing is when 
i compare

```
BOOL day = [[temp_date objectAtIndex:k] compare:[temp_date objectAtIndex:k+1]];
```

it throughs the following expection

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (23) beyond bounds (23)'

thanks in advance

Regards,
sathish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you do everything correct, just check that you're always within array's bounds. If you do that in a loop the condition may be:

```
for (int k = 0; k+1 <temp_date.count; ++k)
   ...
```